# pointer operation in c & c++

Tags: c++, c, pointers, data-structures

```
struct node {

    int data;
    struct node* next;

}

void push (struct node **head, int data) {

    struct node* newNode = malloc (sizeof (struct node));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = *head;
    *head = newNode;     
} 

//I understand c version well.

C++ version

void Stack::push( void *data ) {

        struct node *newNode = new node;
        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;

}
```

In c++ head is a private or protected member of stack class and is declared as node *head.

Question: why head can preserve its value after push() call in c++.
In c, we need to declare it as ** since we want to change the value of head pointer after the push() function call. In c++ code, won’t changes to head be lost after the call?

Comment: Presumably head is a member variable of the class. Which C++ book are you learning from that doesn't cover this?

Comment: I read c++ many years ago but then never used. I used blue cover book at that time. I mainly use c but that also seldom. BTW, this is my first post here and I very much appreciate how the community responds!!

Answer (score 7):

The problem here is the C code you're comparing to C++ is not really analogous.  A better example would be

```
typedef struct Node { 
  int data;
  struct Node* pNext;
} Node;

typedef struct Stack {
  Node* pHead;
} Stack;

void push(Stack* this, int data) {
  Node* newNode = malloc (sizeof (Node));
  newNode->data = data;
  newNode->next = this->head;
  this->head = newNode;  
}
```

In this version we've successfully implemented `push` without having to take a `**` for head.  We have in a way because it's double indirected via the `Stack*`.  But this is very similar to how C++ works.  It's possible to view C++ as passing `this` as a hidden argument to the function.

Comment: To make the point even clearer, you can rename `pStack` to `this` (since the latter isn't a reserved word in C).

Answer (score 3):

In this case, since `Stack::push` is non-static, `head` is a shorthand for `this->head`. So the `head = newNode` is the same as:

```
this->head = newNode;
```